# how to tell if STDIN is bound to a socket or not, in C

Tags: c, sockets, stdin

I am wondering if anyone knows how to tell if the stdin or stdout of bash is bound to a socket or not, in C?

Comment: It is hard to understand exactly what you want to know. What have you tried? Can you illustrate your scenario? (What would an example bash session look like?) Are you looking for [`isatty`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty)?

Comment: You can [test](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Check_output_device_is_a_terminal#C) if a file handle is bound to a terminal or not; I don't think you can test  anything more specific than that (such as if it is bound to a socket).

Comment: Strictly speaking, the answer would be `$(/usr/bin/false)` since you can't connect stdin or stdout directly to a socket in bash. You can connect its file descriptors to a device file (if your OS allows it) that is connected to a socket, but you still read or write to a file.

Comment: The stdin/stdout of the bash may be connected to socket by its parent process. And the parent process doesn't have to take care of creating a pseudo tty. Think about inetd. The reason for testing if the i/o is a socket may be to differentiate between running the script from inetd or in a shell and being more verbose in the later case.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why people downvote this question and why they speak of solving the problem with bash when it is indicated the solution should be in **c**, anyway there are reasonable use cases.

I don't have a real final answer to the question but if I had this problem I would try to use a socket specific call on the file descriptor and check if it succeeds. For instance:

```
// Untested
int socktype;
int optlen = sizeof(int);
if(getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE, &socktype, &optlen) < 0) {
    // this is maybe not a socket ...
    if(ENOTSOCK == errno) {
        // This is not a socket ...
    }
} else {
    // probably a socket ...
}
```

The return value would tell me (not 100% sure though) that the descriptor is a socket or not.

In case it succeeds you could escalate with more specific calls, like using a IP level or TCP level options. This would tell you what kind of socket you have.

See:

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getsockopt.html
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_10.html#tag_02_10_06

Comment: This is an interesting proposal, but can you elaborate a bit on what you are unsure about? Would this code work or not? Why is this not "a real final answer"? Why are you "not 100% sure"? I'd like it if you would bother to test your code :)

Comment: My understanding of the spec tells me it must work, but I didnt test it, so I cannot guarantee it works :)

Answer (score 0):

See [fstat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat). Per this man page, the macro `S_ISSOCK` is not in POSIX so this may not work in all environments.

This code should do it for `stdin`(not tested). To check `stdout`, use `STDOUT_FILENO` instead of `STDIN_FILENO`:

```
struct stat st;

if (fstat(STDIN_FILENO, &st) < 0) {
    perror("fstat on stdin");
    exit(errno);
}

if (S_ISSOCK(st)) {
    /* it is a socket! */
}
```